# How to define Traefik labels in a docker-compose file?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, traefik

```
          traefik:  http://localhost:5002    (development domain to services)
            |       http://localhost:5004    (development dashboard)
            |       http://api.somedomain.com (production domain to services)
            |       http://api.somedomain.com:8080 (production domain to dashboard)
 ___________/
/
|-- Service-1
|   o) http://localhost:5002/account/1      (development)
|   o) http://localhost:5002/account        (development)
|   o) http://api.somedomain.com/account/1  (production)
|   o) http://api.somedomain.com/account    (production)
|
|-- Service-2
|   o) http://localhost:5002/account/1      (development)
|   o) http://localhost:5002/account        (development)
|   o) http://api.somedomain.com/account/1  (production)
|   o) http://api.somedomain.com/account    (production)
```

So given the above routes, I'm not sure how to define my labels in the `docker-compose.yml` and `docker-compose.override.yml` files.

- How to restrict by Host and port?
- How to forward requests (based on the route segments) to 'Service-1' or 'Service-2'.

Also, if I try and go to any route not listed .. like  http://pewpew.localhost:5002 it should reject that request because it doesn't make the hosts in the example routes, above. (e.g. I don't want anything that resolves to the target machine to be accepted).